# Ehcache local transactions with Spring @Transactional

Tags: spring, transactions, ehcache

I'm trying to setup a transactional ehcache, making use of Spring @Cacheable and @Transactional.

My caches work fine with @Cacheable, but as soon as i setup my cache to use a local transaction:

```
<cache name="currencyCodeMaps" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" timeToIdleSeconds="5" timeToLiveSeconds="600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" transactionalMode="local"/>
```

When I access the cache i get error:

```
net.sf.ehcache.transaction.TransactionException: transaction not started
```

even though the same method is annotated @Transactional.
My Spring transaction manager is:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
```

The [ehcache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/transactions#local-transactions) says local transactions are controlled explicitly:

> Local transactions are not controlled by a Transaction Manager.
>   Instead there is an explicit API where a reference is obtained to a
>   TransactionController for the CacheManager using
>   cacheManager.getTransactionController() and the steps in the
>   transaction are called explicitly

But this will be hard, as I want to sync my ehcache transactions with DB transactions, and DB transactions are controlled by @Transactional.

Is there a way to get local Ehcache transactions to work with Spring @Transactional?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to achieve you goal.

1. Because you have 2 transactional resources (JTA and Ehcache) and do not use JTA you have to use compound transaction manager like`org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager` from spring-data project

   ```
   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
       return new ChainedTransactionManager(ehcacheTransactionManager(), jpaTransactionManager());
   }

   @Bean
   public EhcacheTransactionManager ehcacheTransactionManager() {
       return new EhcacheTransactionManager(ehcacheManager().getTransactionController());
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
       return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
   }
   ```
2. You need to specify which transaction manager should be use by default:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class Configuration implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {
   ...
       @Override
       public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
           return transactionManager();
       }
   ...
   }
   ```
3. EhcacheTransactionManager implementation

   ```
   import net.sf.ehcache.TransactionController;
   import net.sf.ehcache.transaction.local.LocalTransactionContext;
   import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
   import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException;
   import org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager;
   import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus;

       public class EhcacheTransactionManager extends AbstractPlatformTransactionManager {

       private TransactionController transactionController;

       public EhcacheTransactionManager(TransactionController transactionController) {
           this.transactionController = transactionController;
       }

       @Override
       protected Object doGetTransaction() throws TransactionException {
           return new EhcacheTransactionObject(transactionController.getCurrentTransactionContext());
       }

       @Override
       protected void doBegin(Object o, TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition) throws TransactionException {
           int timeout = transactionDefinition.getTimeout();
           if (timeout != TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT) {
               transactionController.begin(timeout);
           } else {
               transactionController.begin();
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus defaultTransactionStatus) throws TransactionException {
           transactionController.commit();
       }

       @Override
       protected void doRollback(DefaultTransactionStatus defaultTransactionStatus) throws TransactionException {
           transactionController.rollback();
       }

       public class EhcacheTransactionObject {

           private LocalTransactionContext currentTransactionContext;

           public EhcacheTransactionObject(LocalTransactionContext currentTransactionContext) {
               this.currentTransactionContext = currentTransactionContext;
           }

       }

   }
   ```

source code and test case can be found [here](https://github.com/qnox/spring-cache)

This solution has a significant drawback transaction coordinator of ehcache does not support suspend/resume operations so inner transactions (PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW) are not possible. That is why I had to find another one.

Another option is not to use local ehcache transactions at all and use `org.springframework.cache.transaction.AbstractTransactionSupportingCacheManager#setTransactionAware` which decorates caches to postpone operations until the transaction end. But it has following drawbacks:

1. Evicted keys stay accessible inside transaction until transaction commit
2. `putIfAbsent` operation is not postponed

It was a problem for me, so I implemented this functionality in different way. Check 'me.qnox.springframework.cache.tx.TxAwareCacheManagerProxy', there problems described above was solved, in the same repository

Answer (score 0):

You do not want local transactions, you want XA transactions, which are supported by Ehcache.

Have a look at the documentation for [Ehcache 2.10.x](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-tx_configuring_transactional_cache.html%23) or [Ehcache 2.8.x](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/transactions#configuration).